Proving that the continuous image of a connected set is connected
I just want to know if the following proof is correct or whether or not I need further argumentation in order for it to hold true.

A set M is said to be connected if $M$ cannot be written as $M = U \cup V$, where $U,V$ are non-empty, open and disjoint.


Let $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be a continuous function and $M$ be an open and connected set then $f(M)$ is also connected.

Proof. Suppose we have two open and non-empty sets $U,V \subset f(M)$ such that $f(M) = U \cup V$. We want to show that $U \cap V \neq \emptyset$.
Since $f$ is continuous it holds that $f^{-1}(U)$ and $f^{-1}(V)$ are open as well. t further holds that
$$M \subset f^{-1}(f(M)) = f^{-1}(U \cup V) = U' \cup V',$$
where $U' = f^{-1}(U)$ and $V' = f^{-1}(V)$.
If we now define $U'' := M \cap U'$ and $V''$ analog we get that
$$ M = U'' \cup V''.$$ (we note that $U''$ and $V''$ are non-empty, since $U,V \subset f(M)$ and open because $M$ is open).
Thus - since $M$ is connected - $U''$ and $V''$ are not disjoint and so are $U$ and $V$. $\blacksquare$
Is it possible to drop the openness of $M$?

In the definition of connectedness you have to be careful with the meaning of open:  Even if $M$ is a subset of a nice topological space (like $\mathbb C$) you have to consider the relatively open subsets of $M$ (i.e., open in the relative topology) which are of the form $M\cap U$ with open subsets of $\mathbb C$. And yes, continuous images of connected sets (without further topological properties) are connected.
